# Javascript Specific Field reset with dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, reset

Need some help with some javascript. Not too experience with javascript.  Was wondering if anyone has some snippet for this.

workflow/overview: 
4 fields
user enters data in field 2-4
user selects reset from dropdown menu in field 1
fields reset to default
  - field 2 resets > Please select
  - field 3 resets > blank
fields DOES Not reset
  - field 4 DOES NOT rest > retains entered value

thanks for the help.

Code

```
</script>

    <form name="testform" action="" method="get">
        <fieldset>
            <label>Field 1<font color="red">*</font>:</label>
            <select name="select1" id="select1">
                <option value="Reset">Reset</option>
                <option value="1" selected>1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

            <br/>
            <label>Field 2</label>
            <select name="select2" id="select2">
                <option value="Please select">Please select</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

            </br>
            <label>Field 3</label>
            <input type="text" name="text1" size="100"/>

            </br>
            <label>Field 4</label>
            <input type="text" name="text2" size="100"/>
        </fieldset>

    </form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read a little about javascript, because this is one of the basics (and check out jquery)

mainly to access an item from javascript you can do this : `var element  = document.getElementById('select2')`

now when you have the element "element" that you can put a value in.
element.value = "Please select";

the final code is  :

```
<select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="maybeReset()">

function maybeReset(){
element1  = document.getElementById('select1');

if (element1.value == "Reset")
{
var element  = document.getElementById('select2');
element.value = "Please select";

...
}

}
```